# $a_{m+n}\leq a_ma_n$ implies the convergence of $\sqrt[n]a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be a sequence such that $a_{m+n}\leq a_ma_n$. Prove that $\sqrt[n]a_n$ converges and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]a_n=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sqrt[n]a_n.$$

So far all I have is $\sqrt[n]a_n\leq a_1$ (from $a_{m+n}\leq a_ma_n$ by induction). If it is true that $\sqrt[n]a_n$ monotone decreasing, we are done but I couldn't show it. Should I do something with $\liminf$ and $\limsup$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is monotone decreasing in general. However, the following statement is true, which easily yields the desired result:

> Given $k\in\mathbb N$, we have $\limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le\sqrt[k]{a_k}$.

*Proof.* For any $n>k$, write $n=\beta k+r$, where $\beta,r\in\mathbb N$ and $0<r\le k$. We thus have $a_n\le a_{\beta k}a_{r}\le Aa_k^\beta$, where $A=\max\limits_{i=1,2\ldots, k}a_i$. So
$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le\sqrt[n]A~a_k^{\beta/n}\le\sqrt[n]A~\sqrt[k]{a_k}$$
since $n>\beta k$. The conclusion now follows.

As a consequence, $\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}\le\inf\sqrt[k]{a_k}$. But $\inf\sqrt[k]{a_k}\le\liminf\sqrt[k]{a_k}\le\limsup \sqrt[k]{a_k}$, whence $\inf\sqrt[k]{a_k}=\liminf\sqrt[k]{a_k}=\limsup \sqrt[k]{a_k}=\lim\sqrt[k]{a_k}$.